Difference between :- and => rules without guard?
Are rules declared with the neck (:-) equivalent to ones declared using single-sided unification (=>), in case there is no guard?
eg.
foo(X, Y) :- ...
% vs
bar(X, Y) => ...


No, they are not equivalent. See the docs. At the very least, a SSU rule will throw an error instead of fail if none of the clauses match. Try foo(1) :- true. bar(2) => true.
